# ECS images are failing in gitlab-runner-autoscaling?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs

I am new bie to gitlab-runner, i have tried to setup gitlab-runner-autoscaling but i am unable to download ecr images in a build. When i try to ssh into docker-machine i am able to download images, i even tried to ssh into the VM and tried to pull ecr images as root and as ubuntu user(ubuntu 16.04 AMI), it only fails while running a build .

Please let me know how i can troubleshoot.
 1. How can i find the command gitlab-runner is using to pull ecr image/ 
 2. How to find the user its running the docker command.

```
Runner config:
[[runners]]
  name = "registry-test4"
  limit = 1
  url = "http://gitlab.xxxxxxxx.com/"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.1"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 1
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlab-runner-ci-%s"
    MachineOptions = ["amazonec2-iam-instance-profile=xxxxxxxxxxx", "amazonec2-ssh-user=ubuntu", "amazonec2-region=us-east-1", "amazonec2-instance-type=t2.large", "amazonec2-ami=ami-xxxxx", "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-xxxxx", "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-xxxxx", "amazonec2-zone=a", "amazonec2-root-size=32", "amazonec2-keypair-name=spot", "amazonec2-ssh-keypath=/root/.ssh/spot", "amazonec2-userdata=/etc/gitlab-runner/bootstrap.sh", "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true", "amazonec2-security-group=docker_machine_git_as_prod", "amazonec2-security-group=consul-agent-prod", "amazonec2-private-address-only", "amazonec2-spot-price=x.xx"]
    OffPeakPeriods = ["* * 5-11 * * mon-fri *", "* * * * * sat,sun *"]
    OffPeakTimezone = ""
    OffPeakIdleCount = 1
    OffPeakIdleTime = 1200
```

Error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.2.0 (0a75cdd1)
  on registry-test4 (31b91ac3)
Using Docker executor with image xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/sbt:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfor predefined container...
Pulling docker image xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/sbt:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/dev/sbt/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
---
main:
  image: xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/sbt:latest
  script: sbt +runCI
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue , by installing ecr binary

> https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper

on gitlab-runner server passing these parameters in /root/.docker/config.json. (*earlier ecr was installed only on the VM docker-machine was provisioning.*)

```
{
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```